# How to ROLLUP multiple columns that are joined SELECT statements into a single combined row?

Tags: sql, join, rollup

I am making a view from the table [Data].[FCNP_Log] that has counts of several different attributes for several different 'Production Areas'. What I need is an additional row that says 'All' under the column 'Production Area' and has a total of all the other rows in each of the columns. I almost have what I need, but the following code doesn't quite give me what I need.

```
SELECT 
        ISNULL(total.[Production Area], 'All') AS [Production Area]
    ,   COALESCE(total.[Total], 0) AS [Total]
    ,   COALESCE(inprocess.[In Process], 0) AS [In Process]
    ,   COALESCE(closed.[Closed], 0) AS [Closed]
    ,   COALESCE(nofurtheraction.[No Further Action], 0) AS [No Further Action]
    ,   COALESCE([60day].[60 Day], 0) AS [60 Day]
    ,   COALESCE(dir.[DIR], 0) AS [DIR]
    ,   COALESCE([8d].[8D], 0) AS [8D]
FROM
(SELECT 
        [DEPARTMENT] AS 'Production Area'
    ,   COUNT([FCNP]) AS 'Total'
FROM [Data].[FCNP_Log]
GROUP BY [DEPARTMENT] WITH ROLLUP) total

FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT 
        [DEPARTMENT] AS 'Production Area'
    ,   COUNT([FCNP]) AS 'In Process'
FROM [Data].[FCNP_Log]
WHERE [FCNPStatus] = 'In Process'
GROUP BY [DEPARTMENT] WITH ROLLUP) inprocess

ON
total.[Production Area] = inprocess.[Production Area]

FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT
        [DEPARTMENT] AS 'Production Area'
    ,   COUNT(FCNP) AS 'Closed'
FROM [Data].[FCNP_Log]
WHERE [FCNPStatus] = 'Closed'
GROUP BY [DEPARTMENT] WITH ROLLUP) closed

ON
total.[Production Area] = closed.[Production Area]

FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT
        [DEPARTMENT] AS 'Production Area'
    ,   COUNT([FCNP]) AS 'No Further Action'
FROM [Data].[FCNP_Log]
WHERE [Long_TermCANoFurtherAction] = 1
GROUP BY [DEPARTMENT] WITH ROLLUP) nofurtheraction

ON
total.[Production Area] = nofurtheraction.[Production Area]

FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT
        [DEPARTMENT] AS 'Production Area'
    ,   COUNT([FCNP]) AS '60 Day'
FROM [Data].[FCNP_Log]
WHERE [Long_Term60Day] = 1
GROUP BY [DEPARTMENT] WITH ROLLUP) [60day]

ON
total.[Production Area] = [60day].[Production Area]

FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT
        [DEPARTMENT] AS 'Production Area'
    ,   COUNT([FCNP]) AS 'DIR'
FROM [Data].[FCNP_Log]
WHERE [Long_TermCADIR] = 1
GROUP BY [DEPARTMENT] WITH ROLLUP) dir

ON
total.[Production Area] = dir.[Production Area]

FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT
        [DEPARTMENT] AS 'Production Area'
    ,   COUNT([FCNP]) AS '8D'
FROM [Data].[FCNP_Log]
WHERE [Long_TermCA8D] = 1
GROUP BY [DEPARTMENT] WITH ROLLUP) [8d]

ON
total.[Production Area] = [8d].[Production Area]
```

This code gives me the following table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxbeW.png

As you can see, the ROLLUPs that I have are adding up the columns correctly, but they are staggered, and I need all the 'All' rows to be combined into a single row.

I've tried SELECTing the whole block of code as "t1" and adding an additional GROUP BY t1.[Production Area] WITH ROLLUP at the end, but it's giving me errors.

I feel like there is probably a simple solution but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I did figure out a way to get the results I wanted. I removed all the `WITH ROLLUP` and put `WITH CountTable AS (` before the code above, and the following code afterwards:

```
)


SELECT * FROM CountTable
UNION
SELECT
        'All'                               AS [Production Area]
    ,   SUM(CountTable.[Total])             AS [Total]
    ,   SUM(CountTable.[In Process])        AS [In Process]
    ,   SUM(CountTable.[Closed])            AS [Closed]
    ,   SUM(CountTable.[No Further Action]) AS [No Further Action]
    ,   SUM(CountTable.[60 Day])            AS [60 Day]
    ,   SUM(CountTable.[DIR])               AS [DIR]
    ,   SUM(CountTable.[8D])                AS [8D]
FROM CountTable
```

Comment: Please use CTE to simplify your query. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: I don't understand how that helps?

Comment: Actually I did use that to find an alternative solution. thanks

Comment: please add your solution as answer. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** I did figure out a way to get the results I wanted. I removed all the `WITH ROLLUP` and put `WITH CountTable AS (` before the code above, and the following code afterwards:

```
)


SELECT * FROM CountTable
UNION
SELECT
        'All'                               AS [Production Area]
    ,   SUM(CountTable.[Total])             AS [Total]
    ,   SUM(CountTable.[In Process])        AS [In Process]
    ,   SUM(CountTable.[Closed])            AS [Closed]
    ,   SUM(CountTable.[No Further Action]) AS [No Further Action]
    ,   SUM(CountTable.[60 Day])            AS [60 Day]
    ,   SUM(CountTable.[DIR])               AS [DIR]
    ,   SUM(CountTable.[8D])                AS [8D]
FROM CountTable
```